# Ethers.js: How do I encode an array of addresses into a Solidity bytes variable?

Tags: solidity, encode, ethers.js

I'm testing my Solidity code using Ether.js, and the method under test requires a `bytes` argument, which I'm using to pass an array of addresses:

```
function testFunction(bytes calldata params) external {
   address[] memory addresses = abi.decode(params, (address[]));
}
```

How do I encode an array of addresses in Ethers.js so I can pass it as argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [AbiCoder.encode(types, values)](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/). To encode an array of addresses, you could do:

```js
const abi = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder;
const params = abi.encode(
    ["address[]"], // encode as address array
    [ [addresses.tokens.weth, addresses.tokens.wbtc] ]); // array to encode
```